# How can I sort a defaultdict of list by length of list

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have a `defaultdict` like:

```
d = {'a':[1], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[5,6]}
```

I expect:

```
sorted_d = {'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[5,6], 'a': [1]}
```

How can I sort it by the length of list?

Comment: You need an OrderedDict .

Comment: I tried `sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key = lamda x: len(x), reverse = True)` but failed

Comment: Close. `len(x[1])` would probably be better :-)

Comment: `lambda x: len(x)` is equivalent to `len`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultdict`s - like normal dictionaries - don't have order.

If you just want to iterate over it in a sorted way:

```
for key in sorted(d, key=lambda x:len(d[x]), reverse=True):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries in python are not ordered.

Use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> d = {'a':[1], 'b':[2,3,4], 'c':[5,6]}
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda item: len(item[1]), reverse=True))
OrderedDict([('b', [2, 3, 4]), ('c', [5, 6]), ('a', [1])])
```